# Compiler Error Message: CS0234 namespace not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, service-reference

I'm getting a compiler error with the Service Reference I've added to the .NET project.  The second image show that the Service reference is defined at namespace Jwaala.Site.User.coopBetaServiceTokenProvider, yet I'm still getting a complier error, why?

[image: Compiler error]

[image: Service Reference]

[image: Solution Explorer]

Comment: `coopBetaServiceTokenProvider` is a class, not `namespace`. Your namespace is `Jwaala.Site.User`

Comment: Why is a View referencing a WCF service? I would fix that first

Comment: My Service Reference coopBetaServiceTokenProvider Reference.cs file has the namespace defined as:  namespace Jwaala.Site.User.coopBetaServiceTokenProvider {

Comment: So I shouldn't define a Service Reference in a view?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally there should be a service layer which will handle these WCF connections , that should be ideal/first step to fix.